# A Low Quality Post review just failed, is this a bug?

Tags: bug, review-queues, low-quality-posts

The review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4912976

When this review came up I selected that it was a *link only answer and not spam*, which made the system automatically post a comment from my account onto that answer. This can be seen on the answer itself (both in the audit and [here where it was submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23885768/1317805)).

The problem is that instead of saying that I'd now reviewed this item ([like on the previous review I completed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4912985)), the review page is now saying:

> This item is not reviewable.

The answer itself has not been deleted or edited, nor has the question it was posted on.

**Edit:** It seems someone else has now managed to do this review as well, triggering the system to also post an identical comment from their account:

[image: Example]

The system is ignoring the fact that I already completed this review, and now displays:

> This item is not reviewable. 
>   inf3rno reviewed this 1 min ago: Recommend Deletion

**Edit 2:** The answer itself is now displaying the following:

> deleted by James Donnelly, devnull, Frédéric Hamidi 1 min ago

It seems my comment and delete vote from the review went through okay, but the review itself failed to acknowledge my action on it.

**Edit 3:** Today I've had the same problem once again today on [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4932669). Here is a screenshot of the review page when it fails:

[image: Example]

Today's is slightly different though in that it looks like the review had already been completed by others over 5 minutes before I got there. This might be a separate issue that I was shown this review after it had been completed by others...

Comment: Am I missing something or are both links just regular review tasks, and not audits?

Comment: @Stijn my mistake, I should have used the word "review" instead of "audit". I've edited the post.