# The low-quality review audit system is broken

Tags: bug, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Seriously. Fix the low-quality review audit system or immediately disable the terribly broken audits.

This was the review I got https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6123756

The answer is ***crap***, it just tells the OP to go Google it then drops some links with no further explanation given. If this isn't a link-only answer, then I don't know what is.

The number of up votes and any bounty given to the answer should be irrelevant. I only follow Stack Overflow posting policies when I do reviews. I review objectively. I don't give special treatment to posts depending on their number of votes or the poster's rep.

The flood of people popping up here on Meta who got similar broken audits, shows that this is quite a problem. Particularly the low-quality review audits. It is not an isolated issue and it does matter if you fail audits now and then, if you do 20 per day. Failed audits count up to a temporary review ban.

That the broken audit system claims that this is a good answer and that I'm not paying attention is frankly just insulting. I've had it it now, I will boycott all reviews and all other voluntary moderator work until this is fixed.

---

References to other broken audits:

- [A Low Quality Post review just failed, is this a bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256316/a-low-quality-post-review-just-failed-is-this-a-bug)
- [Empty answer in failed review audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253582/empty-answer-in-failed-review-audit)
- [Failed Audit: Not sure why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266064/failed-audit-not-sure-why)
- [What am I supposed to do with a piece of spam that I review in the Low Quality queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274496/what-am-i-supposed-to-do-with-a-piece-of-spam-that-i-review-in-the-low-quality-q)
- [Is the "STOP! Look and Listen" broken?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272770/is-the-stop-look-and-listen-broken)
- [Review a question, failed audit showing previous (skipped) question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261775/review-a-question-failed-audit-showing-previous-skipped-question)
- [Review Audits: dealing with false negatives and consequences thereof?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272836/review-audits-dealing-with-false-negatives-and-consequences-thereof)
- [Lame "STOP! Look and Listen" even though I tried to edit a bad post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275316/lame-stop-look-and-listen-even-though-i-tried-to-edit-a-bad-post)
- [Is this review audit not off-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271874/is-this-review-audit-not-off-topic/271976#271976)

Comment: Just because you received one incorrect/bad audit doesn't mean the whole queue is broken. I've reviewed it many weeks with no issues.

Comment: @cVplZ It _is_ broken, read meta. Also check the review audits you get, very often it gives you something that a diamond mod has manually deleted, for reasons only apparent to the diamond mod.

Comment: The audit system is broken, sure, but I think we all know that. I think the reason why this isn't being well received is it has no *solution* to the problem. Could you please add what you think would solve this to the question?

Comment: @hichris123 Isn't that what answers are for? Sure I can come up with something, but then I'll post that as an answer...

Comment: "I will boycott all reviews [...]" That's the conclusion I've come to a couple days ago. I've written myself a little script that removes the close and flag buttons from all SO pages.

Comment: That is **still an answer**. It may be a crap answer but without the links it would still be valid. See [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370) You failed the audit fair and square.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's nonsense. As I wrote, either we have rules or we don't. There should be no subjective judgement or fuzzy middle ground. People doing reviews should do so in sync with site policies, not based on their own subjective opinions, moods or artistic creativity. Stack Overflow has a policy against ["just f-ing google it"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255397/lmgtfy-link-cant-be-added) and Stack Overflow has another very clear [policy against link-only answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). End of story.

Comment: @Lundin: I just linked you to the policy. It is an answer, because it is not only a link.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No you didn't, you linked some fuzzy discussion. Policies and rules can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help), as well as in the very site design (lmgtfy is banned).

Comment: @Lundin: you are interpreting the rules quite fuzzily yourself. LMGTFY is banned from comments because it is snarky. If you use it in an answer (or say *you can Google it*) you are liable to be downvoted, but it doesn't make the answer *delete worthy*. Policy is discussed and formed on Meta, the help center summarises but doesn't cover every angle. The discussion I linked to is anything but fuzzy. If you remove the markup and it is still an answer, it stays.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Even without the Google discussion, the answer is still "barely more than a link to an external site". And even if SO policies say this this answer is fine, _then why do answers 100% equivalent to this one show up in the other side of the review audits?_ A one-liner with a link, if you don't click delete, you fail the audit and get banned.

Comment: I would definitely say that answer should be a comment and in any case is way too fuzzy to be an audit if it generates this much debate anyways. Certainly not an answer to be held out as an example of what's good.

Comment: The automated system is not ideal, but it is not *broken*. It provides users with a constant stream of audits that *for the vast majority* produce excellent test cases. The few exceptions cause people to yell loudly here on Meta, but the fact remains that these are the minority. The system throws out hundreds of tests daily you don't hear anything about. And I still disagree that that answer qualifies as a link-only answer.

Comment: @eddie_cat I think that's the problem. The algorithm that generates these things can't tell what makes a good answer and what makes a bad one. An answer which has many up votes is not necessarily following SO policies. And an answer which was deleted by a diamond mod is not necessarily a bad one by its own merit: the diamond mod could have deleted the answer because of things regular users don't see. Such as: the poster is a bot, the poster is spamming the same answer all over, the question is a community wiki and the mod tries to clear out or merge identical answers etc etc.

Comment: At any rate, the diversity in up and down votes for this post shows that there's a schism among meta users here. The review audit system as it currently stands, be it flawlessly correct, horribly broken or anything in between, is annoying a large amount of people who do/did volunteer moderator duties on SO.

Comment: IMO it may not be "broken" but it does kind of suck. When you have people complaining about the audit system so often and then you have other users saying "well you should have recognized it was an audit and treated it differently than all other reviews on that basis" I think that shows that there is a problem. It's not at all intuitive to use even if you are able to avoid getting burned by clearly wrong review audits.

Comment: The fact that you're proposing removing audits means you pretty clearly have never lived in a world without audits, and don't realize how much worse that world is.  Audits have their problems, sure, and there is certainly room for improvement, but they're doing way more good than harm.  Yes there are bad audits, but they're rare and quite easy to deal with.

Comment: I would think that, with a day's work, someone could create plenty of examples of posts that violate one or more quality standards and use these specific examples in audits.  Hell, even just run the algorithm for selecting posts for audits, then have someone accept or trash it.  Spend a few hours doing that and you could have thousands of guaranteed good audits in the pipe.  The whole random audit thing just doesn't need to happen.

Comment: I've had the exact same issue. Really weird audit posts. I've only failed 2 audits in the last 110 and it gave me a two day ban. The second one was seriously flawed.

Comment: Speaking of insulting, I felt particularly insulted when I was unknowingly quizzed on this. I spent quite a bit of time thinking and reviewing and then after however many (I can't remember) it was like "JK! This was just a test! OK, now we'll show you real ones". I just closed the tab. It was insulting to me as a user on SO for so many years I'd be secretly quizzed if I knew how to use the site or not.

Comment: The close and flag buttons won't audit you @Louis, so I'm not sure why you're doing it or how it's related.

Comment: I've just removed a feature request from your list of bad reviews. Your list is still highly disingenuous, some of the questions are bugs in the way deleted questions are displayed post-audit; did you read any of them?

Comment: Why, by the way, it tells that you used "Recommend deletion", if it should be "Delete"?

Comment: @Ben My issue only partially overlaps Lundin's. I'm ok with the audits but I'm tired of being told that link-only answers should be preserved, that I should edit them, or that I'm acting in bad faith. (Editing other people's posts I something I rarely do in any circumstances. Has nothing to do with SO: it's just the way I am.) I can chose whichever way I want to spend my time. I've decided my time would be better spent doing something else than closing and flagging. Whether this is a net gain or loss for the site is something for someone with undoubtedly more acumen than I have to decide.

Answer (score 28):

To me that answer is not a link only answer. The actual answer is:

> What you're trying to do is called memorization.

The additional advice is:

> Don't try to do this yourself, use a library.

Which in some languages is perfectly valid advice. For example, there have been lots of questions I've seen on SO where someone was trying to implement memorization and the code doesn't work. There could be lots of things tripping people up: closures, scope, binding etc.

Also, in some languages (Perl for example and increasingly javascript) the culture is to avoid re-implementing the wheel and use libraries as much as possible so that the community as a whole develops informal "standards" which lead to easier to understand code (at least code with minimal surprises).

It is perfectly OK not to give an implementation if an explanation suffices.

It is perfectly OK to provide links to external libraries if it's helpful and the question isn't asking "what's the best library for doing this?".

It is perfectly OK to give people terms to Google since even if you know what you're looking for sometimes you can't Google it because you can't figure out what phrase to Google. Googling is a skill not everyone is great at.

So before voting that answer as low quality, stop, look, and listen. Don't be a robot or policy lawyer and vote solely based on how many policy checkmarks you can cross off.

Comment: *"vote solely based on how many policy checkmarks you can cross off"*: What..! So if I follow the policies I'm going to fail audits and finally get banned from review because there are policies that can be crossed off according to circumstances..! I think then we should document them like - "This policy can be crossed off under circumstances such as..."

Comment: @TJ: Actually, flagging that as "**very** low quality", please delete, unambiguously goes against the policy. Downvoting it for being low-quality, I profess I cannot properly judge that one.

Comment: @Deduplicator I am referring to what is quoted from the answer, not a particular post...

Comment: -1 because you concentrate on answering the question that has not been asked (is that particular answer low quality) and not on answering the actual issue (which is, problematic audits with answers, that need meta posts to check if they are low quality or not).

Answer (score 22):

I probably would have voted Looks OK on this specific post. It does have more information than just the links, including a term that the poster apparently thought would be useful ("Memoization").

But no matter what the call is, I don't think it's a good audit. Audits should be posts where the decision is clear to anybody who has a good handle on the site policies, and is actually reading the post. This one is certainly not an example of a great post where voting to delete is flat out wrong.

And I do agree that the audit system/selection is broken. The arguments against this point of view normally are:

1. There are ways of recognizing audits.
2. These are just isolated cases. Most audits are good.

Argument 1 completely misses the point. Reviewers should not have to play detective, and look for clues that are signs of audits, in order to handle them correctly. They should be able to treat them like any other review, and not fail them if they make a reasonable decision based on the merits of the post.

Argument 2 is harder to disprove. Most of us only see the audits they encounter themselves. But based on my limited data, I disagree with it. I had done about 4,500 reviews without any trouble (a very small number of isolated failed audits, must have been less than 1 failed audit per 1,000 reviews), and then failed 4 audits within a little over a week. This resulted in a 2 day and then a 7 day review ban. Of the 4 I failed, I would argue that 1 was questionable (I probably should have voted differently, but it was not crystal clear), and 3 were bogus. If you review a lot (which I did at the time), I think it's just a question of chance if you do or do not get a few bad audits in a row. I had not changed anything in the way I reviewed.

I'll exclude the Edit Review queue from this. Those audits are very obvious, and you really have to be asleep at the wheel (or have a mouse/trackpad accident) to fail them.

The sad part is that there are constructive suggestions on how this could be addressed, but there seems to be nothing that is done about it. I stopped reviewing at least for now. My "strike" might not be permanent, but I've had enough of this for a while. And I feel that I'm not the only one. The result is that people who took their reviewing seriously, even though it's an activity with little reward, stop reviewing. And the Close Review queue never gets smaller.

Comment: "Audits should be posts where the decision is clear to anybody who has a good handle on the site policies, and is actually reading the post." That's just a glorified way of saying that users vote incorrectly, which is true.

Comment: @Uni: so the 'fix' is educating the voters.

Answer (score 6):

It is not very useful, but it is an answer.

We don't delete material for being low-quality, we downvote it.

Deletion is for answers which violate the rules.  Rules like, the "no link-only answers" which means it should still provide information even if all the links break.  Indeed this answer does not rely on its links.  If all the links broke, a reader would still know that:

- The technique they need is called *memoization*
- Mathworks employee Loren Shure has written an explanation of using memoization in MATLAB, which is freely available somewhere out there.

These are on-topic and valid bits of information.  Clearly an answer with more explanation and some example code would be better, but this still is an answer.  Separate the barely anything from really good using the vote buttons.

If you failed an audit for trying to downvote this answer, there'd be a problem.  But deletion is not the right response, and "STOP!  LOOK!  THINK!" is exactly the message you needed to see after trying.

Comment: *"We don't delete material for being low-quality, we downvote it."* Then why does the queue present an option for deletion?? And not present an option for voting??

Comment: @Radiodef: Because it is the "**very** low quality queue". Low-quality is downvoted, **very** low quality (utter crap / pure garbage) deleted. It was not utter crap.

Comment: @Deduplicator No, it's just "Low Quality Posts". VLQ is only one of the flags that sends stuff there.

Comment: Yeah, literally it's not link only, it's google only. So google only answers are now allowed?

Comment: @РСТȢѸФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ, I know but I have to agree that "there is this term you should be looking up" can actually help someone.

Answer (score 6):

> That the broken audit system claims that **this is a good answer** and that I'm not paying attention is frankly just insulting.

So hold on, let's be clear. The principle options presented are:

[image: to delete or not to delete]

I don't think there is anywhere that forces you to assert this is a *good* answer, only whether to delete it or not.

Now some of the people defending the audit are saying that if you think it's bad you should downvote it, but this is not an option presented from within the queue. So if anything, the problem with the queue is you have to leave it to execute the 'proper' action.

Comment: On other queues, there are voting actions in a different part of the screen.  They are disabled on that queue, even though downvoting is very often the most appropriate response.

Answer (score -4):

I'd like to reply specifically to one of the comments you posted above, since I feel it highlights an important aspect of the broader issue:

> "@MartijnPieters Even without the Google discussion, the answer is still "barely more than a link to an external site". And even if SO policies say this this answer is fine, then why do answers 100% equivalent to this one show up in the other side of the review audits? A one-liner with a link, if you don't click delete, you fail the audit and get banned."   – Lundin, [2014-10-31 12:57:43Z](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275793/the-low-quality-review-audit-system-is-broken#comment112589_275793)

If you think that all "one-liner with a link" answers are "100% equivalent", and equally deserving (or undeserving) of deletion, then I'm not surprised that you're feeling frustrated by review audits, and by seemingly contradictory policies, and by other users' voting behavior.

That's because, when it comes to judging the quality of an answer, as perceived by most people, the important thing is *not* how long the answer is or how many links it contains.  What actually matters is how *useful* the answer is, and specifically:

- Does it answer the question?
- Did it help the OP solve their problem?
- If someone else with the same problem finds it on Google, is it likely to help them too?
- Will it remain useful even 10 years from now, after any links in it have broken?

Sure, for *most* one-liner answers with a link, the answer to all those questions is most likely "No."  That makes "one-liner with a link" a useful sign when looking for bad answers — it tells you to pay extra attention to this answer, because there's a good chance that it's bad.

But that doesn't mean that *all* one-liner answers with a link are bad.  Sometimes, a short answer can be enough to answer the question, and the presence of a link doesn't always mean that the answer would be useless without it.  The answer you got as an audit seems to be one of those cases.

Am I saying that that answer is perfect?  No, certainly not.  But it *does* meet the basic criteria for being a valid and useful answer; as, indeed, demonstrated by the fact that the OP clearly found it useful enough to accept it and even to award a bounty for it.

It you go around blindly voting to delete answers just because they're short and have links, you're going to delete a lot of crap — but you're also going to delete some useful answers as well.  Answers whose deletion would *not* make the Internet, or even that particular page on Stack Overflow, a better place.

Comment: There is a policy against link-only answers. You can have your opinion that link only answers should stay, but recommending to leave them does not solve the OPs problem, it creates the worse one - "looking ok" the link-only answers would result in even more failed audits.

Comment: If we have a policy against link-only answers, then end of story. It should then be the responsibility of the _person writing the answer_ to ensure that their post is good-enough quality to not get dismissed as link-only. Now if you happen to disagree with SO's link-only policy, you are of course welcome to raise a debate on meta. But ultimately the meta discussions must yield some consensus that make it into the official SO help and site design. Until then, we follow the current policies. The alternative is chaos with the "individual reviewer creativity" deciding outcome of reviews.

Comment: @РСТ: The thing is, we *don't* have a policy against "one-line answers with a link".  We have [a policy against answers that contain no information other than a link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers), but that's *not* the same thing. Sometimes one line of text, with or without a link, really is enough to answer the question.